# Defining routes in AJAX and Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Error I get: `undefined variable article_id`.

What I am trying to achieve : Define the correct route in AJAX and Rails.

What I need: The structure `articles/1/comments/2`.

Goal: Note that my goal is to only load `comment` using AJAX, not `article`.

In the AJAX script below what I currently have *undefined* is `article_id`, for which I wrote the following:

```
  var getArticle = function () {
    return $('.article-title').each(function() {
      var article_id = $(this).data('article-id');
  });
};

$(document).ready(getArticle);
```

AJAX:

```
 var loadComment = function() {
  return $('.comment-content').each(function() {
    var comment_id = $(this).data('comment-id');
    return $.ajax({
      url: "/articles/" + article_id + "/comments/" + comment_id,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'script',
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        return console.log("AJAX Error: " + textStatus);
      },
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        return console.log("Worked OK!");
      }
    });
  });
};

$(document).ready(loadComment);

$(document).on('page:change', loadComment);
```

Index:

```
  - @articles.each do |article|
    %article-title{ :class => "article-title", "data-article-id" => article.id }= article.title
    - article.comments.each do |comment|
      %comment-content{ :id => "comment-#{comment.id}" }
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your `routes.rb`

```
resources :articles do
  resources :comments
end
```

And add the following controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
    render json: @comment
  end
end
```

Running something like:

```
curl http://localhost:3000/articles/123/comments/456.json
```

will set the `params[:article_id]` to `123` and the `params[:id]` to `456`, the `id` is intended to be used as a comment id.

Comment: Routes were defined as stated, and just added the json page. Now what? I still get undefined variable and I think it has to do with my definition of  the `getArticle` function.

Comment: I don't quite get the purpose of your `getArticle` function, but 1. Check using chrome/firefox inspector that the 'data-article-id' is actually in the DOM, 2. Add a `console.log` statement in the `getArticle` to see that the `.article-title` elements were actually found.

Comment: Okay, so I just realized I had a problem with my HAML. It's all fixed now and the HTML and JS are elements corresponding. Now, the purpose of the of my `getArticle` function is to load the `articles/article_id/comments/comment_id URL.